# Css Dropdownlist disappear

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

My dropdown list disappear when I mouse over it. I am pretty sure its CSS error but could not fix it. Here is my website: http://www.maximosturkey.com/  (header menu which I need to fix).

I already try to fix it with margin and padding but no result..

```
           #menu-header ul  {
           padding-bottom: 0;
           padding-top: 0;
           line-height: 80px;
                            }
```

Can someone check site and tell me what is wrong?

I use custom-css plugin so I can add new css code to website quickly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add a `padding-bottom` to you menu links,like so:

```
.sf-menu li a{
padding-bottom:15px;
}
```

and check result

همچنین امیدوارم بزودی بتوانیم از املاک شما در ترکیه خونه بخریم :)